# How do I get started with Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've been looking online and have found that the stuff about SSJS is a bit confusing. How do I get started with Server-Side JavaScript? Can it be used with any web host?

So far, I've downloaded the Node.js program from the official website, installed it, setup PATH (which the installer does) and I've copied/pasted the code snippet:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

that is displayed on the main page into example.js, then opened the node cmd and entered: "**node.js example.js**" (without quotes) and all I get in return is:

...

But I should be getting:

> "Hello, world!"

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Go the browser and go to `http://127.0.0.1:1337/` and see what you're getting. You should get Hello Word there.

Comment: @VarunAchar Sorry, "This page cannot be displayed." :/

Comment: the book called `Learning Node.js` is pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

I think your command line should just be 'node example.js'

Comment: thanks for your answer. That doesn't work either though. All I get in the (node) cmd window is "...", and in the browser I get "This page cannot be displayed."

Comment: Save this code in test.js or something else and on cmd do this

node test.js without any quotes 

and paste http://127.0.0.1:1337/ on browser

press enter and that's it